# How to check inside a fragment if device language has been changed while the app was running in background?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to refresh the activity inside a fragment when the device language is changed and app is running in background.

I created this method to recreate the activity but I don't know when to call this method and how to check if the language has been changed.

```
 private fun recreateActivity() {
    val intent = activity!!.intent
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
    activity!!.finish()
    activity!!.overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
    startActivity(intent)
    activity!!.overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
}
```

Can you tell me how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

When the app comes to foreground `onResume` lifecycle method of the activity will be called, where you can user the below code to get country and language:

```
Locale locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

The locale consists of two things: language and country.